# i want to change group1() to "*" / in python / used re.sub()

Tags: python, regex

example

```
re.sub("(a)(b)", "*", "abc")
```

group 1 (a)

group 2 (b)

i want to change group1 to "*", only

answer is *bc

What should I do?

plz, give me a hint

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead instead matching a and asserting b to the right without a capture group, and replace with `*`

```
a(?=b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5geGvU/1)

```
import re

re.sub("a(?=b)", "*", "abc")
```

Output

```
*bc
```

---

Or using a single capture group for what you want to keep, and use that in the replacement using `\1`

Note that you don't have to capture what you don't want in the replacement.

```
re.sub("a(b)", r"*\1", "abc")
```

Comment: Wow, thank you.
I think you can solve my problem your way.